# Filtrar datas em que usuário entrou em nosso sistema

Tags: mysql, sql, algoritmo-de-busca, filtro

Estou tentando filtrar as datas em que os usuários se conectam em meu sistema.

Tem um porem, primeiro preciso filtrar para que não tenha usuários duplicado.

Já estou fazendo isso usando o argumento **DISTINCT** em minha consulta, com resultado que minha consulta está retornando, quero pesquisar na coluna **DATA**, para saber todos os dias que os usuários se conectaram ao meu site.

Estou utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    wps_history
WHERE 
    inserted
BETWEEN "2016-11-01 00:00:00" AND "2016-11-30 23:59:59"
```

Este comando me trás todos os resultados, porem isso esta dando mais de *40 mil* linhas, realizando o filtro **DISTINCT** o resultado e filtrado para *500 linhas*, estou usando o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    user_id
FROM
    wps_history
WHERE
    inserted
BETWEEN
    "2016-11-01 00:00:00" AND "2016-11-30 23:59:59"
```

Agora estou querendo saber como posso usar o comando acima e trazer as datas em que cada `USER_ID` se conectou ao meu sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não utilize o `DISTINCT` para isso, utilize `GROUP BY`pelo código do usuário:

Caso queira a última data:

```
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(inserted)
  FROM wps_history
 WHERE inserted BETWEEN '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-30 23:59:59'
 GROUP BY user_id
```

Caso queira a primeira data:

```
SELECT user_id,
       MIN(inserted)
  FROM wps_history
 WHERE inserted BETWEEN '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-30 23:59:59'
 GROUP BY user_id
```

Caso queira agrupar tudo em uma coluna só:

```
SELECT user_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(inserted, '%d-%m-%Y') separator ', ') as datas
  FROM wps_history
 WHERE inserted BETWEEN '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-30 23:59:59'
 GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Olá, Sorack, muito obrigado.

Porém preciso de todas as datas dentro do período, neste caso de 30 dias. Como posso adaptar o código para que ele retorne todas as datas em que ouve conexão durante os 30 dias.

Obrigado pela dica do (GROUP BY).

Eu estou engatinhando na programação e estou gostando muito!

Valeu

Comment: @CíceroAlves disponha. Caso a resposta tenha resolvido o seu problema não esqueça de marcar o ✅ para aceitá-la. Assim poderá utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Comment: Ela me ajudou, mas não resolveu completamente meu problema, pois preciso de todas as datas em que cada user_id se conectou no período de 30 dias. A Dica do GROUP BY já foi uma novidade para mim, VAleu mesmo!

Comment: @CíceroAlves especifique na pergunta qual o banco de dados que você está utilizando para que eu possa complementar minha resposta

Comment: @CíceroAlves tenta `BETWEEN GETDATE() -30 AND GETDATE()`. Sql-Server.

Comment: @Sorack, Uso o MySQL.

A Coluna da tabela "WPS_HISTORY" que registra sempre que um usuário se conecta é "DATA", quero saber quais usuários "USER_ID", se conectaram no período de 30 dias.

Obrigado pela atenção, se puder me recomendar alguns livros para ler sobre o assunto ficarei grato!

Comment: @CíceroAlves você quer mostrar todas as datas em uma coluna só?

Comment: @Sorack a exibição pode ser de qualquer forma

Comment: @Marconi, valeu.

Comment: @CíceroAlves da uma olhada na resposta que eu adicionei no final agora

Comment: @Sorack muito obrigado! Agora foi!